# Incomplete history of a file in git (git-svn)

Tags: git, git-svn

How should one go about viewing full history of a file's content in git?

A file has a very short history in git, repository synced over git-svn, but a long history in svn. The history in git reaches to the point where the file was moved. To view the history I use the following command:

```
git log PATH_TO_FILE
```

Am I doing it right? Git is supposed to track content not files, I was imagining it would be good at tracking history of files across renames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
git log --follow PATH_TO_FILE
```

Comment: Indeed. From the manual: --follow: Continue listing the history of a file beyond renames. Surely, that should be on by default.

Comment: @luntain: It only works when examining a single path, and it probably has a bit of a performance penalty. It also encourages some SVN sort of thinking, where there can only be one identity for a given set of content, called a file.

Comment: Does this (--follow) work if the file was re-organised from a different svn repository?